# A deterministic execution time measure

Tags: c++, cplex

Some algorithms depend on a time measure. E.g., 10% of the time, follow approach A. If that does not work, follow B for 20% of the time. If that does not work, do C.

Measuring execution time in seconds is non-deterministic. Cache state, interleaving non-user tasks on a core, or even simply the dynamic boost of a modern processor's clock speed are external influences that alter the execution time of otherwise deterministic code. Hence, the algorithm might behave non-deterministically if classic execution time measures are used.

To keep the algorithm behaving deterministically, I'm looking for a deterministic way to measure execution time. This is possible, e.g., the CPLEX solver has a deterministic time measure called [ticks](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/progr_consid/timing/determinism_defn.html).

I know this simple question does not have a simple answer. So let me narrow it down a little:

- The determinism property is a hard constraint. I'd rather have a measure that only very weakly correlates with measured execution time, as long as it is deterministic.
- Ideally, the deterministic time measure measures the whole program execution, including statically compiled libraries. But if this is not possible, then measuring the execution time of the source code I can modify is fine.
- I'm willing to take a 100% performance hit, but not more. Less of a performance hit would be better though :)
- It's ok if the compiled binary is no longer portable among different CPU models.

Some approaches I have considered, but don't know how hard they are to implement or how well they will work:

- modifying a compiler to add a command incrementing a global counter inbetween each other command in the compiled code. This seems like the most principled approach, and may in theory even work for statically compiled libraries.
- counting the number of memory accesses. No idea how to do this in practice. Probably also by modifying a compiler?
- counting the number of if-statements and loop condition checks using a global counter in the source code. This can be done easily by, e.g., macros, but it will overlook many library calls (e.g., a simple call to sort a vector will not increase the counter), and hence may not correlate much with the actual execution time.
- accessing [hardware performance counters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_performance_counter) to, e.g., count the number of instructions of a process, perhaps through a library such as [PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi). The problem here is that I think these counters are non-deterministic as well?

So, how to deterministically measure the execution time of a program?

Edit: measuring cpu time (e.g. by the `clock()` function) is definitely better than my naive wall clock time examples. However, measuring cpu time is by no means deterministic: runs of the same deterministic program will yield different cpu times. I'm really looking for a deterministic measure (or a measure of "work done" as @mevets calls it).

Comment: Would using an RTOS of some sort be an option?

Comment: If your deterministic measure of time does not match the actual measure of time, what is the value of it?  I'm imagining a report that says "according to deterministic analysis of the program, it should take 5 seconds to execute, but actual measurements report 5 seconds plus or minus 5 seconds."

Comment: @Wyck I guess the question is how to remove or reduce the influence of context switches, external processor load, etc. on this method switching.

Comment: @Wyck the value is that there is an indication of how long a part of the algorithm has been running. Even a rough measure is better than none.

Comment: I feel like what you want is just [profiling via instrumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/understanding-performance-collection-methods?view=vs-2017#instrumentation).

Comment: @Wyck Yeah, instrumentation to collect, e.g., the number of jump statements or memory access may be worth looking into.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Didn't know about "Real Time Operating Systems". Are they fully deterministic?

Comment: @HolKann Timings are specified. These are the kind of OS:es you typically would use in the situations you describe. How you _use_ those timings is up to you. Used correctly, you may indeed find a solution there.

Answer (score 1):

You can access process time (number of clock cycles used by the process) instead of wall clock time (time elapsed including any other processes that context-switched in between) by calling the C standard library function `clock()`. There are `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` clock ticks in one second. Note that this may run faster than wall clock time if your program is multithreaded -- i.e., it measures clock cycles consumed by the program over all processor cores. Therefore, `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` clock ticks refers to one second of compute time on one processor core. To implement the switching between methods, you could use asynchronous I/O (such as with newfangled C++20 coroutines, or Boost coroutines), checking process time occassionally, or you could do timed software interrupts that set a flag which is picked up by the main thread of execution, which then switches to a new method.

You probably don't want to increment a counter after each instruction. That creates enormous compute overhead and gums up your processor pipeline because every other instruction depends on the instruction 2 before it, and also your instruction cache.

Code example (POSIX):

```
static /* possibly thread_local */ std::atomic<int> method;
void interrupt_handler(int signal_code) {
    method.fetch_add(1);
}

void calculation(/* input */) {
    auto prev_signal_handler = signal(SIGINT, &interrupt_handler);
    
    try {
        method.store(0);
        int prev_method = 0;

        // schedule timer interrupts
        for (size_t num_ns : /* list of times, in ns */) {
            timer_t t_id;
            sigevent ev;
            ev.sigev_notify = SIGNAL;
            ev.sigev_signo = SIGINT;
            ev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &t_id;
            timer_create(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &ev, &t_id);
            itimerspec t_spec;
            t_spec.it_interval.tv_sec = t_spec.it_value.tv_sec = num_ns / 1000000000;
            t_spec.it_interval.tv_nsec = t_spec.it_value.tv_nsec = num_ns % 1000000000;
            timer_settime(t_id, 0, &t_spec, nullptr);
        }

        bool done = false;
        while (!done) {
            int current_method = method.load();
            if (current_method != prev_method) {
                // switch method
            }
            else {
                // continue using current method
            }
        }
    }
    catch (...) {
        signal(SIGINT, prev_signal_handler);
        throw;
    }
    
    signal(SIGINT, prev_signal_handler);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mired with some detailed solutions that potentially extensively change the code, probably because those are the only approaches you're familiar with, but this is IMHO short sighted. You cannot at this point know for sure that instrumenting the generated code in such an invasive way has merit. Let's step back for a minute.

> Some algorithms depend on a time measure. E.g., 10% of the time, follow approach A. If that does not work, follow B for 20% of the time. If that does not work, do C.

I don't think it's true. It's an arbitrary constraint, that's not general at all. The algorithms depend on the "effort", and often real time is a very poor substitute for effort. As you have well stated, any sort of "time" is mired in architectural specifics.

Another problem is the assumption that the algorithms are the units of change. They are generally not, i.e. you don't have as much control here as you think you do, unless you code all the numerical parts in assembly, or thoroughly audit the generated code. Each algorithm, if it succeeds, may produce slightly different results depending on numerical error stackups due to the architecture-dependent selections done by the generated code at runtime. It's a thing, compilers and/or their runtime libraries do plenty of that! So the idea that running the same compiled floating point code on various PCs and will produce bit-identical results is correct as long as your goal is to show it incorrect, but in reality it'll prove incorrect at some later time when you'll be too deep into it to realistically implement the huge changes needed for a fix.

But inside the algorithm you should have plenty of arbitrary points where you can increment a counter - not too often, and use the value of the counter as a measure of effort your algorithm has expended. It doesn't matter much that such a measure has a different scaling factor to "real time", for each algorithm, because real time is not the true requirement here. All you really want is some deterministic way to carry out a decision to switch algorithms, and you can roughly calibrate these arbitrary switchover points to real time once, and keep this calibration frozen: it doesn't really matter exactly, only that you can clearly decide when to switch.

Furthermore, there's some caution to be had when an algorithm produces a result ("converges") very close to the effort threshold. Due to architectural differences, the exact effort required to achieve "convergence" in terms of a fixed floating point threshold may slightly vary between CPU generations. So instead of being a hard cutoff, you need some way of expressing hysteresis, so that if the convergence happens close to the effort cut-off, some more alternative criterion is used for either threshold or convergence, but you'd need to do proper statistical modeling to show that the alternates are sufficiently reliable.

Comment: Interesting point of view. You are right that there is a difference between "time" and "effort", and that relying on time will change the behavior of the program with hardware (e.g., CPU) and software (e.g., OS) changes. 

Using "count points" in the algorithm to measure effort is actually what I'm currently doing. The problem, however, is that for a significant set of inputs, my current set of  "count points" is a very poor measure of "effort", and, e.g., leads to using approach A 99% of the (cpu) time. Figuring out what the relevant count points are for all inputs seems hard...

Comment: Effort scaling is how it's often handled. Say you have a loop that inverts matrices. Inverting a 1000 3x3 matrices is very different than inverting a 1000 128x128 matrices. So the effort is a product of the number of operations (here: inversions) and of the estimate of the operation cost, e.g. N^2 for the matrix size. You'd have to provide a rough outline of what your algorithms do, in numerical terms, if you'd want more detailed suggestions, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

A counter can handle units of work, but is each unit of equal value (ie. time)?  The service clock(3) provides an approximate virtual time of execution -- that is time elapsed while your process is actually running, as opposed to real world (wall) time.

Similarly, timer_create may accept clock ids similar to CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, which permits you to raise a signal after a certain cpu time has passed.  Providing your app can be arbitrarily interrupted without entering a undefined state, you could use this to switch from method 1 -> 2 -> 3.

Although better than counting blocks of work, you will need to accept a certain inaccuracy around the exact time to account for system overhead, cache contention, etc..